# Chrome Driver starting in Spanish instead of English

Tags: java, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I using chrome driver to execute my test, but for some reason the driver is starting in spanish instead of English, and this is affecting some date format in my test

The installed version of Chrome is on English, but I'm not sure why the chrome driver starts on spanish, my best guest is that windows is on spanish

```
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.vChromeBrowserPath);
                options.addArguments("--test-type");
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--lang=US");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the parameter lang=

it should be options.addArguments("--lang=en"); instead of "us"